# Counting occurrences of a value in second dataframe with filter

Tags: python, performance, dataframe

I am trying to count the occurrence of an id value between two time periods in a second dataframe, and append the value as a column in the first dataframe.

I currently have the following code, which solves the problem fine but causes a large bottleneck in my application.

```
import pandas as pd

dfA = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D'],
    'start': [1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6],
    'end': [3, 6, 7, 5, 7, 7, 8, 10]}) 

dfB = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D'],
    'time': [1, 5, 2, 6, 8, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 5, 3, 6]})


def count(start, end, df_id, dfB):
    dfA_valid = dfB[(dfB.time >= start) & 
                      (dfB.time <= end) &
                      (dfB.id == df_id)]
    dfA_count = len(dfA_valid.index)
    return dfA_count
    
    
def get_counts(dfA, dfB):
    dfA['count'] = dfA.apply(lambda x: count(
                            x['start'], x['end'], 
                            x['id'], dfB), axis = 1)
    return dfA

dfA_solved = get_counts(dfA.copy(), dfB)
```

dfA is c.1 million rows and dfB is c.2 million rows and this section is taking a long time to run. Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Do you know which part of the solution is taking the most time? Is there just a part of the solution which is the bottleneck?

Comment: I have tried to narrow down the problem to the fewest lines of code. The last line in the block above is the one taking the most time in the application, I'm not sure how I could narrow this down further.

Comment: Is 'end' always greater than 'start'?

Comment: For your real data what do you get for y['count'] == x['counts']`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool. I will try two things, to rewrite a bit the code and parallelization.

To reproduce the initial data

```
import pandas as pd
import time

dfA = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D'],
    'start': [1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6],
    'end': [3, 6, 7, 5, 7, 7, 8, 10]})

dfB = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D'],
    'time': [1, 5, 2, 6, 8, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 5, 3, 6]})
```

But we want to have more to check scalability. Feel free to change the values of N:

```
# Create bigger samples
N =15
for i in range(0,N):
    #print(i)
    dfB = pd.concat([dfB,dfB])

N =6
for i in range(0,N):
    #print(i)
    dfA = pd.concat([dfA,dfA])

print('shape dfB ',dfB.shape)
print('shape dfA ',dfA.shape)
```

For my case the output is:

```
shape dfB  (425984, 2)
shape dfA  (512, 3)
```

Now I have a good data size to play.

```
def count(start, end, df_id, dfB):
    dfA_valid = dfB[(dfB.time >= start) &
                    (dfB.time <= end) &
                    (dfB.id == df_id)]
    dfA_count = len(dfA_valid.index)
    return dfA_count




def get_counts(dfA, dfB):
    dfA['count'] = dfA.apply(lambda x: count(
        x['start'], x['end'],
        x['id'], dfB), axis=1)
    return dfA


start = time.time()
dfA_solved = get_counts(dfA.copy(), dfB)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Reproduce previous code:

14.757256031036377 seconds in my machine

I think the way to count can be simpler:

```
# This is to use index for search
dfB.set_index('id',inplace=True)
#dfB.reset_index(inplace=True)

def count(start, end, df_id, dfB):
    # This is to reduce the search
    dfA_valid = dfB.loc[df_id,:].copy()
    return  ((dfA_valid.time >= start) &
    (dfA_valid.time <= end)).sum()



def get_counts(dfA):
    dfA['count'] = dfA.apply(lambda x: count(
        x['start'], x['end'],
        x['id'], dfB), axis=1)
    return dfA



start = time.time()
dfA_solved = get_counts(dfA.copy())
end = time.time()
print("Changes on count function ",end - start)
```

Down do 7 seconds.

But if we really want to way further we need to parallelize.

```
"""Now with parallelization"""
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import  Pool,cpu_count

num_cores = cpu_count()
num_partitions = num_cores-1


def parallelize(data, func):
    data_split = np.array_split(data, num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

start = time.time()
dfA_solved = parallelize(dfA, get_counts)
end = time.time()
print("Changes on count function and parallelization ",end - start)
```

Down to 4 seconds.

```
shape dfB  (425984, 2)
shape dfA  (512, 3)
14.757256031036377
Changes on count function  7.768801212310791
Changes on count function and parallelization  4.349687814712524
```