# How do I pickle a "memoized" Python function?

Tags: python, query-optimization, dill

I have the following code:

```
def f(input,MEM={}):
    if len(MEM) == 0:
        with open('dill.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            MEM = dill.load(f)
    if input not in MEM:
        intended_output = complex_function(input)
        MEM[input] = intended_output
    return MEM[input]
```

Running long batches of inputs, I have found that my code runs much slower than if I hadn't loaded `MEM` originally. ie, with

```
def f(input,MEM={}):
    if len(MEM) == -1:
        return None
    if input not in MEM:
        intended_output = complex_function(input)
        MEM[input] = intended_output
    return MEM[input]
```

And I run both `f` and `f2` for a four thousand inputs, it takes half an hour for `f` to complete, but only 40 seconds for `f2` to complete. Is this because when I load `MEM` with dill, it represented by structure which is slower to access? I have tried copying and deepcopying MEM, this only makes the issue worse (especially with deepcopy, then it takes multiple seconds to do even the smaller inputs).

Comment: Not sure if related to the problem, but (1) if you use `with open(...)`, you don't need `f.close()`; (2) you aren't using `f` at all!?

Comment: Oops, I meant to write ```MEM = dump(f)```. I did not know about ```f.close()``` being unnecessary, I have changed this too now.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change the speed of my code noticeably.

Comment: If you want to add your own answer, please add it as an answer instead of editing it into the question.

Comment: I'm the `dill` author. You may want to check out how `klepto` uses `dill`. `klepto` is a caching library that leverages `dill` to help with the memoization..

Comment: oh cool, I'll look into ```klepto```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> MEM = dill.load(...)
> ```

This creates a new local variable called `MEM` but does not change the default argument `MEM`.

Therefore the default argument `MEM` is an empty dictionary and the file is unpickled *each time* the function is called.

To actually change the default argument, you could simply use instead:

```
MEM.update(dill.load(...))
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sense to un-pickle only once or the less as possible.
2. When running the function for many cases, better avoid loops and use instead functions such as .apply that leverages C code.
3. Perhaps you could parallelize, so you can use all your cores to do the task. Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66079049/7127519

Comment: I know that the for loops are not the main issue. I have included dummy for loops in ```f2``` and it runs satisfactorily fast. Regarding (1), how do I un-pickle only once? I am very new to dill.

Comment: Perhaps you could un-pick outside the function and at the beginning.

Comment: I mean, the first if statement will only be true once. Thus, I don't see this being useful... Oh, unless perhaps this is causing ```MEM``` to not be saved after each call!